# R frequency tables only for certain values

Tags: r, frequency, proportions

I have a vector with 15 values ranging from 1 to 4.

`values <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,2,2,1,3,1,2,4)`

Lets say this is an item in a questionnaire and 15 people got asked a certain question.
1 to 2 means, the respondant is referring to that question with a "No", while the values 3 or 4 indiciate a positive response to that question. I only want to find out the percentage of those who gave a positive answer, hence the amount of respondants who answedred with a 3 or 4, divided by the total amount of all participants.

I started with `table()` and `prop.table()`:

`round(prop.table(table(values)), 2)` which yields to

```
   1    2    3    4 
0.33 0.40 0.20 0.07
```

Is there a way to use prop.table so that it gives me the percentage of those who indicated a 3 OR a 4 (and only those). Should I dichotomize the values first?

The result should look something like this:

```
values
0.27
```

Answer (score 1):

One option that avoids modifying or creating new data is to use `prop.table` after creating a logic table with `%in%`:

```
prop.table(table(values %in% c(3,4)))

# or 
# proportions(table(values %in% c(3,4))) # Thanks @GKi

#    FALSE      TRUE 
#0.7333333 0.2666667
```

The line `values %in% c(3,4)` creates a Boolean vector the same length as the data `values`. `table` and `prop.table` then summarize it. Since R mathematically interprets `TRUE`/`FALSE` as 1/0, respectively, it will return the proportion.

If you only wanted the single proportion instead of both:

```
prop.table(table(values %in% c(3,4)))["TRUE"] # Thanks @GKi

# or 
# proportions(table(values %in% c(3,4)))["TRUE"] 

#     TRUE 
#0.2666667
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is only one class, you can use `mean`.

```
mean(values > 2)
#mean(values %in% c(3,4)) #Alternative
#[1] 0.2666667
```